# How to access state of different reducers in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a situation where I need to access auth related data into another module

For example.

I have two different reducer files

- auth.js
- todo.js

Now I need to access auth reducer state into todo, and for that, i have combined the reducer

But when I try to console the props, I am unable to access the auth data into the todo module

Do we have any simple approach for that, do let me know about that

Answer (score 1):

Think you have to you mapStateToProps

```
function mapStateToProps(state){

  return {
      auth: state.auth,
      todo: state.todo

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consolidate your reducers in a Redux store. Traditionally, you would do this by `import {createStore, combineReducers} from "redux"`

And set up your store like:

```
const store = createStore(combineReducers({
   auth: authReducer,
   todo: todoReducer
}))
```

That way your connected components have access to both reducer states at any given time. Otherwise, there's no real point in blending the data between both reducers. Reducers should be handling their own piece of state and they should act independently as such.

Comment: I have already done this, but unable to get the status details of auth into todo module

Comment: What is it do you mean by "todo module", do you mean a component, or another reducer?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution while doing R & D by myself

Problem is that I was using only todo reducer into my todo module, but if we need to use the different reducer data than we need to map the states separately just like below

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const auth =
    state.get('auth') && state.get('auth').toJS && state.get('auth').toJS();
  const todo =
    state.get('todo') && state.get('todo').toJS && state.get('todo').toJS();
  return {
    ...auth,
    ...todo
  };
};
```

this is how we can access multiple state data into our modules using mapStateToProps and can return it based on the business requirement